# Error connecting Analysis Services Cube using Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, ssas, linked-server

I am trying to create a Linked Server from SSMS.The linked server should connect to a Analysis database cube.I am using this connection below.
[image]

and security

[image]

But I am getting the below error each time I test connection

[image]

Can you let me know what could be the reason behind this

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

The test connection to the linked server failed.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "XXXX".
OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "XXX" returned message "The physical TCP/IP connection failed: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ".
OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for linked server "XXXX" returned message "The peer prematurely closed the connection.". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.3356&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=7303&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Please let me know what could be reason behind not able to connect to analysis service ,whereas with the same settings I am able to connect from a different box

Answer (score 1):

You probably have problems with differences in **kerberos encryption protocol** for accounts running SQL and SSAS. Check that by following command:

```
Get-ADuser SERVICEACCOUNT -Properties * |select KerberosEncryptionType
```

If you got empty for one service account and AES128/AES256 for another this means that ticket can not be decrypted because of difference in protocols.

In that case you should set **kerberos encryption protocol** (aka **KerberosEncryptionType**; aka **msds-supportedencryptiontypes**) for the account which does not have it specified:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity SERVICEACCOUNT -KerberosEncryptionType AES128,AES256
```

Why this happens and how to check other reasons you may read in my article - https://www.sqlpill.com/tips/kerberos-encryption-protocol/